# Finding Expected Value of Conditional Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Consider a random variable X ~ Poisson (1). Namely, $P(x=k) = \frac{e^{-1}}{k!}$ , k=0,1,2,...

I'm trying to solve for $\mathbb{E}\{X|X\geq 1\}$.

My approach:

Given that $X\geq1$ then we know that at least one person has arrived (using arrival / no arrival terminology). Using the fact that Poisson is *memoryless* then $\mathbb{E}\{X\}=\mathbb{E}\{Y+1\}$  where $Y$ has the same distribution as above Poisson distribution. The solution afterwards is really simple.

Is that approach correct?

Comment: Poisson *distribution* is not memoryless.

Comment: Sorry I meant the process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the equality: $$\mathbb EX=\mathbb E[X\mid X\geq1]P(X\geq1)+\mathbb E[X\mid X=0]P(X=0)$$leading to:$$1=\mathbb E[X\mid X\geq1](1-P(X=0))=\mathbb E[X\mid X\geq1](1-e^{-1})$$

hence to:$$\mathbb E[X\mid X\geq1]=\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}=\frac{e}{e-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

It is $\frac {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} ke^{-1} \frac1 {k!}} {1-P(X=0)}$ and $P(X=0)=e^{-1}$. Can you compute the sum?

The answer is $\frac e {e-1}$.

Comment: You are using the formula of conditional probabilities right ? Denominator is clear its P(X>=1) which is 1-P(X=0) which is the evaluation of our distribution at X=0. For the numerator P(X=x and X>=1) how do you get that though?

Comment: @HasanHammoud $E(X|X\geq1 )=\frac {E(X 1_{X\geq 1})} {P(X \geq 1)}$. For the numerator multiply the values $X=k$  ($k \geq 1$ )by their probabilities and sum over $k$.

Comment: But when you are working in the conditional space we have a new probability mass function don't we ? You are using the same pmf in the expectation sum as that of X but in the conditional space its different isnt it ?

Comment: @HasanHammoud The two pmfs are equal up to the multiplicative constant $P(X\geq 1)$, which is exactly the denominator.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you guys but I still have a question on the approach ... E[X|X>=1] = Sum over x of (x. PMF X|X>=1 (x|x>=1) ). This P X|X>=1 (x|x>=1) as you said is the P(X=k and X>=1)/(1-P(X=0)). Now P(X=k and X>=1) = P(X=k) for k>=1 is that correct?


Why is the method I proposed wrong do you have any idea ? Like why can't we say X=Y+1 and then E[X] = 1+ E[Y] = 1 + lambda

Comment: @HasanHammoud You seem to think that under condition $X\geq1$ random variable $X-1$ has Poisson distribution. This however is not the case. Just explore $$P(X-1=k\mid X\geq1)=\frac{P(X=k+1)}{P(X\geq1)}=\frac{P(X=k+1)}{1-P(X=0)}$$ to see that.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out !